# Geth API Implementation. Help Required!

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, goethe

I am trying to make APIs in Go by using the **[ethapi](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/ethapi/backend.go)**. 
I need to call the below method from my golang code but i'm not able to call it. Can anyone help me?

**[func GetAPIs (apiBackend Backend) []rpc.API](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/ethapi/backend.go#L73)**

Answer (score 1):

In Go you can't import an external package if the import path contains the word *internal* otherwise you get the error `use of internal package not allowed`. The *ethapi* is an internal package.

[source](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit)

Comment: Is there a fork of Go without stuff like remote dependencies, invalid use of internal, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I am working in an open-source project to develop a new ethereum compatible blockchain replacing the default PoW by the PoA provided by Tendermint protocol.

To aim that we had to reimplement some of Ethereum APIs, such as `net` or `miner`, because in PoA they have different behaviour.

```
import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth" 

func ... (..) .. {
   ethereum, err := eth.New(ctx, ethCfg); // Init ethereum node
   apis := ethereum.APIs(); // Fetch available ethereum apis
}
```

If you want to see more how we did that check our repository [Lightchain](https://github.com/lightstreams-network/lightchain), more specifically [at this method](https://github.com/lightstreams-network/lightchain/blob/c8544a97653bb1f6ca4846661255c0fbe96cc9dd/database/database.go#L121).

I hope it was useful! :)

Comment: Your answer seems to be unrelated to the question asked about help using the Ethereum api in go.

Comment: IMHO it is, as I pasted a link to an example on how to do it. To sum up:
```
import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth"
...
ethereum, err := eth.New(ctx, ethCfg);
ethereum.APIs(); 
```
You need to initialize a ethereum node object and then you can fetch the APIs

Comment: Please then put this code directly in the answer and remove the need to go to your external site.